# How to use symmetricDS in Embedded mode

Tags: symmetricds

I have the following use case:
A database A (Master) and a database B (slave), located on diferent machines.
I want to synchronize the Database A with Database B.
I want to create a java application using SymmetricDS embedded.
As there is no documentation on how to perform this, i want a sample example or a documentation . 
Please help me I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this an example how run the Symmetric engine server in embedded mode , and it works perfectley for me :

```js
public class ClientNode {
 private ClientSymmetricEngine cEngine;
 private File propFile;


 public ClientNode(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
  propFile = file;
  Properties propertiesFile = new Properties();
  propertiesFile.load(new FileReader(propFile));
  cEngine = new ClientSymmetricEngine(propertiesFile, true);
  getcEngine().openRegistration("client", "001");// client is the name of the node group and 001 is the ID
  getcEngine().setup();
  getcEngine().start();
 }

 public ClientSymmetricEngine getcEngine() {
  return cEngine;
 }

 public void setcEngine(ClientSymmetricEngine cEngine) {
  this.cEngine = cEngine;
 }
}
```

Main class :

```js
public static void main(String[] args) {
 
    
 try {
  new ClientNode(new File("client.properties"));
  SymmetricWebServer node = new SymmetricWebServer("master.properties");
  node.setWebAppDir("Web"); 
  node.setJoin(false);
  node.start();
  // this will stop the node
  //node.stop();
  }catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
    
 }
```

Properties  files :

client.properties :

```
external.id=001
engine.name=client-001
sync.url=http\://localhost\:31415/sync/client-001
group.id=client
db.url=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost/easyexchangedb_slave
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.user=root
registration.url=http\://localhost\:31415/sync/server
db.password=
```

master.properties :

```
external.id=server
engine.name=server
sync.url=http\://localhost\:31415/sync/server
group.id=server
db.url=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost/easyexchangedb_master
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.user=root
registration.url=http\://localhost\:31415/sync/server
db.password=
auto.registration=true
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a section in the documentation about embedding symmetricDs engine into Java SE application: http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.6/user-guide/html-single/user-guide.html#deployment-options-embedded

Comment: thank you ,i've seen it but, it wasn't helpful from me, any i way i have found an example and it works perfectly.

Comment: It would be nice to post a link to the example so other people could benefit from your findings.